# Find a maximum of: $x^{2016} \cdot y+y^{2016} \cdot z+z^{2016} \cdot x $

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

$x,y,z \ge 0  $  ,   $  x+y+z =1$

Find a maximum of:
$$x^{2016} \cdot y+y^{2016} \cdot z+z^{2016} \cdot x $$

and when it is reached.

**my attempt:**

1) $$x^{2016} \cdot y+y^{2016} \cdot z+z^{2016} \cdot x \le $$
$$\le \left( \frac{2016x+y}{2017}\right)^{2017}+...$$

2) $z=1-x-y$
$$f(x;y)=x^{2016} \cdot y+y^{2016} \cdot (1-x-y)+(1-x-y)^{2016} \cdot x $$

$$\frac{df}{dx}=2016x^{2015}\cdot y-y^{2016}+(1-x-y)^{2016} -2016(1-x-y)^{2015}x $$

$$\frac{df}{dy}=...$$

Comment: Shouldnt it be $2017$ in cube root

Comment: Attempt (1) will most likely not work since you found a lower bound for the expression, but you want an upper bound.

Comment: What about so idea: assume $x = \frac{1}{3}$ and $y = \frac{1}{3} - \epsilon$, $z = \frac{1}{3} + \epsilon$ , then represent this expression:
$\frac{1}{3}((\frac{1}{3})^{2016} + (\frac{1}{3}+\epsilon)^{2016} + (\frac{1}{3} - \epsilon)^{2016}) - \epsilon ((\frac{1}{3} - \epsilon)^{2016} - (\frac{1}{3} + \epsilon)^{2016})$. Now using that fact that second scope more than $0$ we should make it lower.

Comment: Is this a question from an on-going contest?

Comment: $x^{2016}y\approx0$ unless $x\approx1$. So we need $x$ almost 1, $y=1-x,z=0$ (or similar). Maximising we get $x=\frac{2016}{2017},y=\frac{1}{2017},z=0$ and result $\approx 0.00018$.

Comment: @Joel Reyes Noche: I think not

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: why comment and not answer?

Comment: @Roman83 now I can do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $x\geq y\geq z$

Hence, $x^{2016}y+y^{2016}z+z^{2016}x\leq(x+z)^{2016}y=2016^{2016}\left(\frac{x+z}{2016}\right)^{2016}y\leq$

$\leq2016^{2016}\left(\frac{2016\cdot\frac{x+z}{2016}+y}{2017}\right)^{2017}=\frac{2016^{2016}}{2017^{2017}}$.

2. $x\geq z\geq y$.

In this case $x^{2016}y+y^{2016}z+z^{2016}x\leq x^{2016}z+y^{2016}x+z^{2016}y\leq(x+y)^{2016}z=$

$=2016^{2016}\left(\frac{x+y}{2016}\right)^{2016}z\leq2016^{2016}\left(\frac{2016\cdot\frac{x+y}{2016}+z}{2017}\right)^{2017}=\frac{2016^{2016}}{2017^{2017}}$.

Comment: how to obtain the inequality in the second line with $(x + z)^{2016}$?

Comment: @Roman83 because $(x+z)^{2016}y\geq x^{2016}y+2016x^{2015}zy$